# Vue SPA to force page reload when using vue-router navigation

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, vuejs2, amazon-cloudfront, vue-router

**Scenario:**

I have a Vue2 SPA ready to replace a legacy LAMP website but PO would like to deploy it progressively (starting with just one single URL) to test user's reactions, analytics, ad revenue, etc.

We've built this architecture to allow this approach:

[image: Architecture]

It works. So, if you go to http://example.com/release-first (let's say this is the page we want to release publicly in the first place) CF returns the content from the S3, and any other URL is fetched from the legacy server.

But, of course, when you access `/release-first` you're in the SPA, and since most of the navigation is done with `<router-link :to="">`, you're *trapped* in the SPA and you can access the rest of the new version, which we don't want at this point.

**Possible solutions I thought:**

One solution could be to replace all `<router-link>` tags with standard `<a>` links that would force the browser to do a new petition to the CloudFront every time. That might work but I'd prefer not to do it because I have to change a lot of links and also because links are not the only way the user can move around (there's some form submission too, etc.)

So, I tried something like:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (!/\/release-first\/?$/.test(to.path)) {
        window.location.href = `http://example.com${to.path}`  
        return;
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

This works fine in `staging` env (because it has a different subdomain, so it's redirecting to production) but if I try in production it doesn't work. I don't know if Vue hijacks the [Location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) or what, but it doesn't force a new petition to the CloudFront.

I've also tried with:

```
const absolutePath = `http://example.com${to.path}`;
window.history.pushState({ urlPath: absolutePath }, "", absolutePath);
window.location.reload();
```

But it doesn't work either... and I couldn't find in `vue-router`'s [Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/) an option to force the page to reload on navigation. Any idea on how to achieve this?

---

**Extra information requested in comments:**

- Router mode is `history`.
- Path formats are like:

  - `/`
  - `/single-level-pages`
  - `/two/level-pages`
  - `/two-levels-with/:param`
  - `/multiple/level/pages`
  - `/multiple/level/with/:param/`
- Not all paths share the `release-first` URL. The URL I wanna release in first place is like `first-level-with/an-specific-param`.
- I've double-checked the RegExp (and I've used a console.log there too). The redirections in CloudFront are working well too. If you enter the different URLs in the browser you get content from Legacy server or S3 as expected. The code I've used in `beforeEach` navigation guard works fine in staging too, so the only issue is that this in not enough when the domain is the same because the `location.href` overwrite doesn't seem to force a new request when the destination is in the same domain.

Comment: Did you tried to use the hook afterEach ? The hook is called after navigation occurred but before the DOM is updated.

Comment: it seems `/\/release-first\/?$/` only match root url, for the url with sub route like `/release-first/xx` will not work.

Comment: I haven't tried @Zysce, I'll give it a try...

Comment: Thanks @Sphinx, that's not the problem. This is just a demo, the real regexp is not the one I used here, but it's working (as I said, it works fine in `staging` environment, because it has a different subdomain and `location.href` causes the desired reload)

Comment: @JordiNebot, could you post out the codes for router configuration?

Comment: @Sphinx what are you interested in exactly? I mean the configuration is standard: importing `vue-router`, having Vue to _use_ Router, defining paths as `{ path, name, component... }` objects... Everything is working fine, the only relevant part is the navigation hook `beforeEach` that I already posted...

Comment: @JordiNebot,  what is the mode for your router? history or hash? what is the path format, always begin with `release-first`?

Comment: Thanks for your clarification @Sphinx. I've updated the question.

Comment: if so, what is the redirect rule in your server for 'S3 with Vue SPA'? check the instruction at [Vue router: history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)

Comment: Thanks again @Sphinx, but I've double-checked the regexp (and I've used a console.log there too). The redirections in CloudFront are working well too. If you enter the different URLs in the browser you get content from Legacy server or S3 as expected. The code I've used in beforeEach hook works fine in `staging` too, so the only issue is that this in not enough when the domain is the same because the `location.href` overwrite doesn't seem to force a new request when the destination is in the same domain.

Comment: @Sphinx With all due respect and being super grateful for your help effort, your fiddle has nothing to do with my question... This fiddle is not a Vue App, so it's not using `<router-link>` but `<a>` tags (if you read my question again you'll see how I suggest that one possible solution would be to use `<a>` tags but I'd like to avoid that).

Comment: @JordiNebot, check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5rzaeo4/9/) which uses `<router-link>` then it works fine.. probably you want to give one try like `setTimeout(()=>{window.location.href = 'http://example.com${to.path}' })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I finally solved it:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (
        window.location.host === "prod-env.example.com" &&
        /\/release-first/.test(from.path) &&
        !/\/release-first/.test(to.path)
    ) {
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.id = "forceReloadLink";
        a.href = to.path;
        document.querySelector("body").appendChild(a);
        document.getElementById("forceReloadLink").click();
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```